# Animate plot in pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

I browsed through the gallery of animated example under pgf but didn't find my answer.

I would like this kind of pictures: take 4 points located at `(0,0)`, `(1,0)`, `(5,0)` and `(7,0)`; for `r` varying from `0` to `2` by step `0.2`, 
draw a circle of radius  `r cm` around each of these points (a frame corresponds to a value of `r`); below the circles, draw four lines,
the first ends at `r=0.5`, the second ends at `r=1`, i.e `\draw (0,-3) -- (min(r,1), -3);`

I'm stuck with the computation of the minimum since I don't know what kind of variable should be `r` (a counter, a sort of argument) and with the varying sizes of the circle because I don't know how to indicate the unit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to see what you did so far.

Comment: There are two parts actually. First is to draw the picture and second is to animate it. So two big questions without any code duh!.

Comment: And how should be those four lines drawn?  " draw four lines, the first ends at r=0.5 the second ends at r=1 i.e \draw (0,-3) -- (min(r,1), -3); " is not clear. For minimum you can use `\pgfmathmin{x1}{x2}\pgfmathresult`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of the problem, particualrly of the segments that should be drawn is not clear, but you can adapt my example to suit your needs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \Value in {0,1,5,7}
{
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (\Value cm,0) {};
\foreach \Radius [count=\xi] in {0,0.2,...,2}
  {
  \draw[visible on=<\xi>] (\Value,0) circle (\Radius cm);
  \draw[visible on=<\xi>] (\Value,-3cm) -- ++({min(\Radius,1)},0pt);  
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The resulting animation:

[image]

If you are not using beamer, you can still use my code and produce the animation with the [`animate`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/animate) package.

Comment: OK done. May I ask what the code invisible/visible is for ?

Comment: @LaurentD. Thanks. That code prevents the elements from jumping. The drawing for all elements is performed on all slides, but with `visible on` you can control on which slides you want an element to be visible.